# 1st and 2nd order centered difference

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

[Find 1st and 2nd order derivative of given function at x=2 using centered differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N9CS.jpg)

I tried several resources through google, tried stephen boyds applied linear algebra and steven c. chapra's applied numerical method with matlab too but couldn't understand how to solve it. Can anyone please help? [ I don't want you to solve it for me, I just want to understand the theory and I couldn't find any resource which explains centered difference, so anything related to centered difference will be helpful for me]

[It is solved using centered difference approximations, thanks to those who helped]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Math Stack Exchange is not a "Problem and Solution" site. Kind people here will try to help you by reviewing your own solution, improving your current thoughts, or giving you the right approach and sometimes (maybe often) full solution. So please, consider adding more details to your post including the source of this problem and your own attempt to tackle this problem.

Comment: @VIVID I know, I didn't actually want the solution, I wanted if anyone could give me a heads up or guide me from where I can learn the topic. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Think about Taylor expansion around a *central* point

Comment: Are you expected to find numerical approximations, or to derive the exact formula as limit of the difference quotients?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes trying that right now

Comment: @LutzLehmann numerical approximations

Comment: As these are second error order approximations, set $h=10^{-5}$ and compute $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$ etc. Try with variations of the step size, double and half, or with factors of 10, to see how the approximation depends on $h$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thanks I solved it by using various step size, your suggestion helped me there, I'm grateful :)